# Change Edgeform for specific boxes in BoxWhiskerChart

Tags: charts

I would like to change every second member of a pair in a `BoxWhiskerChart` to have a dashed `EdgeForm`.

I can create a chart where all the boxes have the dashed `EdgeForm`. For example, the following creates four pairs of data blocks, and colors each block a particular color,

```
data = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[a, 1], 100], {a, {0, 3, 2, 5}}, {2}];

BoxWhiskerChart[data, ChartStyle -> {{Red, Green, Blue, Black}, None}, 
       ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Dashed]]
```

which creates a chart that will look something like,
[image]

However I don't know how to change the `EdgeForm` to dashed for only every second member of each pair.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 4):

```
BoxWhiskerChart[data, 
 ChartStyle -> {{Red, Green, Blue, Black}, {EdgeForm[Thick], EdgeForm[Dashed]}}]
```

[image]

Or

```
Show[{
  BoxWhiskerChart[ReplacePart[data, {i_, 2} -> None], 
   ChartStyle -> {{Red, Green, Blue, Black}, None}, 
   ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Thick]],
  BoxWhiskerChart[ReplacePart[data, {i_, 1} -> None], 
   ChartStyle -> {{Red, Green, Blue, Black}, None}, 
   ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Dashed]]
  }]
```

[image: Out]

Answer (score 0):

```
styleddata = data;
styleddata[[All, -1]] = Style[#, EdgeForm[{Thick, Dashed}]] & /@ styleddata[[All, -1]];

BoxWhiskerChart[styleddata, ChartStyle -> {{Red, Green, Blue, Black}, None}]
```

[image]